# Selecting dates less than a specific one

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro for my daily reports. When have a new report with different effective dates, it only captures the specific ones indicated in my recorded macro.

I want to instead capture “all dates prior to the coverage period”, which is in cell D2 (8/1/2017). Every month that date changes to the current coverage period.

My questions:

- For the `Criteria2` “Acct Enroll” and “Acct Reinst”: Instead of Array (with only the dates below), is there a code to say dates less than the coverage period in cell D2?
- Is there another way to select the entire sheet instead of: `Rows("1:1000").Select` ?

I want to thank you so much in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AAHDAILY()
'
' AAHDAILY Macro
'
    Sheets("original data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$35").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
        "ACCT ENROLL"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$35").AutoFilter Field:=14, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "10/1/2015", 0, "6/1/2014", 0, "4/1/2013", 0, _
        "1/1/2007")  
    Rows("1:1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Retro Enrolls"
'
    Sheets("original data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$35").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
        "ACCT REINST"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$35").AutoFilter Field:=14, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "11/1/2015")
    Rows("1:1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F29").Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Retro Reinstates"  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column N contains dates (and not just text that looks like dates) and that cell D2 also contains a date, you could change

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$35").AutoFilter Field:=14, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "10/1/2015", 0, "6/1/2014", 0, "4/1/2013", 0, _
    "1/1/2007")
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$35").AutoFilter Field:=14, _
                                            Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                            Criteria1:="<" & ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value2
```

i.e. the criteria is any dates less than the date in cell D2.

---

Refactoring your code would give:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AAHDAILY()
'
' AAHDAILY Macro
'
    'Use a "With" block to save typing
    With Worksheets("original data").Range("$A$1:$AA$35")
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, _
                    Criteria1:="ACCT ENROLL"
        .AutoFilter Field:=14, _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, _
                    Criteria1:="<" & .Range("D2").Value2
        'Create a new worksheet and give it a name
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("original data")).Name = "Retro Enrolls"
        'Copy the entire range to the new worksheet (will only copy visible rows)
        .Copy Worksheets("Retro Enrolls").Range("A1")
'
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, _
                    Criteria1:="ACCT REINST"
        .AutoFilter Field:=14, _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                    Criteria1:=Array(0, "11/1/2015")
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("original data")).Name = "Retro Reinstates"
        .Copy Worksheets("Retro Reinstates").Range("A1")

        'Switch off the filter
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that tomorrow morning when I get to work.